# how to load selected columns from one table to another

Tags: hiveql, cloudera

i am trying to load selected columns from one table to another in cloudera hive using:

`Insert into ent_upd(logtype, 
                     process_name, 
                     process_id_un, 
                     process_id_2_un, 
                     process_timestamp, 
                     description) 
 select logtype, 
        process_name, 
        process_id_un,
        process_id_2_un, 
        process_timestamp,
        description 
   from lstnobjcreate;`

when this error pops up,i dont know how to resolve it so kindly help me out..

`Error while compiling statement: FAILED: NullPointerException null`

i cannot insert using `select *` command because the target table has more columns then the source table.,I would appreciate if any one could help me out with loading specific columns from one table to another in hive without any errors such as

`Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10044]: line 9:60 Cannot insert into target table because column number/types are different 'ent_upd': Table insclause-0 has 9 columns, but query has 6 columns.`

thanks.

Comment: did u set the below variable ,it verifies column types      hive.typecheck.on.insert

Comment: no..i was trying to insert 6 columns in 9 column target table...which was my mistake..now i have replaced the remaining column with null values the problem has been solved. thank you for your help..appreciate it